# Does iptables protect from kernel vulnerabilities?

Tags: kernel, iptables

I read a lot of kernel vulnerabilities which are beyond my understanding. I would like to reduce the risk of an issue related to one.

If I block everything other than SSH on a server, will this help to block from kernel vulnerabilities before they even happen, or are they exposed before the firewall has a chance to drop traffic?

I guess the ultimate security is to put a seperate firewall in front of the important server?

Comment: Closing services certainly reduces the amount of available network-related vulnerabilities... It doesn't have much to do with "kernel vulnerabilities" in the end, since you're just reducing the number of services your machine is providing (and could therefore be compromised through).

Answer (score 2):

No, iptables does not protect you from kernel vulnerabilities. In fact, [iptables can also become an attack vector](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2014-2523/). There are other places where exploitable vulnerabilities could occur:

- [The network driver](http://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2009-1389/).
- [The SSH daemon itself](http://www.openssh.com/security.html).
- If you have sshd configured with weak passwords and someone manages to bruteforce it, then local privilege escalation exploits can be tried. The firewall is typically unlikely to be able to catch these kind of attacks as it exploits an application vulnerability.

The best way to protect yourself against these is by taking preventive measures such as not using weak passwords, not exposing the host to the Internet unless necessary, staying current by applying software patches, etc.